# How this div align the middle?

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/hq8q8eqg/1/)

I want to align second div to be middle of first div...I tried to do this with `vertical-align:middle` but not working.

It is because we put the container `display: table`?

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="container-logo">
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div class="profile-name">NAME</div>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.container-logo {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;}

.logo{
        clear: none;
    float: left;
    height: 57px;
    width: auto;
    background:red;
}

.profile-name{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    color: blue;
    /* line-height: 22px; */
    font-size: 14pt;
    background:aqua;
    font-family: Montserrat regular;
}
```

What is the problem it does not work ... Can you give me some advice please?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

My items must be in line and have the same height ... I just want the second div to put it in the middle of the first ... exactly the same height

Comment: Check css, it's .container not .container-logo in your html.

Comment: soory I edited my post

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Looks like the Fiddle is updated.

Comment: @Marius You should edit the code in your question too.

Comment: *"I want to align second div to be middle of first div"*, so the second `div` should be inside and in the middle of the first, correct?  Could you be more clear on exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I want to be in the middle of the first div ... unless we can possibly do a print screen

Comment: @Marius Then the second div needs to be inside the first, [are you looking for something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/hq8q8eqg/6/)? Either that or you could force the position with absolute positioning in the CSS if they for some reason must be apart (but I don't recommend that).

Comment: without modifying anything you cant achieve, since float never allows to have anything vertical align.. i can see in my example that both div's are in same height and vertically centered.. if this is not ur requirement, better post a screenshot of wat u r exactly looking for.. so that some one can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container-logo">
```

Replace the class name.

```css
    .container-logo {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.logo{
    clear: none;
    /*float: left;*/
    height: 57px;
    width: auto;
    background:red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.profile-name{
    /*float: left;*/
    width: auto;
    
    /* line-height: 22px; */
    
    font-family: Montserrat regular;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.profile-name p{
    font-size: 14pt;
    background:aqua;
    color: blue;
    padding:2px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container-logo">
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div class="profile-name">
        <p>NAME</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, I was wrong when I wrote code ... Now the question is correct

Comment: Ohh okay , please check now I update it. Is it working for you >?

Comment: divul blue to be the middle of the red ... without modifying anything ... now in your example divs have the same height

Comment: Okay please check now

Comment: @Marius You stated that the first div needs to be inside and in the middle of the second one, and they need to be the same height. If this is the answer you are looking for please update your question to reflex, otherwise it's very unclear what you seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove float:left from the classes `.logo` and `.profile-name` with `display:table-cell` will help you fixing this.. like the below

**CSS**

```
.logo{
        clear: none;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 57px;
    width: auto;
    background:red;
}

.profile-name{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: auto;
    color: blue;
    /* line-height: 22px; */
    font-size: 14pt;
    background:aqua;
    font-family: Montserrat regular;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hq8q8eqg/2/)

Comment: but my items must be in line ... putting out float: left only are

Comment: thats wat iam trying to say, check the fiddle and let me know https://jsfiddle.net/hq8q8eqg/3/

Comment: div blue to be the middle of the red ... without modifying anything ... now in your example div`s have the same height

Comment: without modifying anything you cant achieve, since float never allows to have anything vertical align.. i can see in my example that both div's are in same height and vertically centered.. if this is not ur requirement, better post a screenshot of wat u r exactly looking for.. so that some one can help you

Answer (score 0):

Use table-cell for inner divs and remove floats:

```css
.container-logo {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo{
        clear: none;
    /* float: left; */
    height: 57px;
    width: auto;
    background:red;
}

.profile-name{
    /* float: left; */
    width: auto;
    color: blue;
    /* line-height: 22px; */
    font-size: 14pt;
    background:aqua;
    font-family: Montserrat regular;
}
.container-logo > div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-logo">
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div class="profile-name">NAME</div>
</div>
```

Or inline-block if you want to get like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hq8q8eqg/5/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your second div inside first one then write your html like this

```
<div class="container-logo">
 <div class="logo">LOGO
   <div class="profile-name">NAME</div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

and in your css do something like this

```
.container-logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    height: 100%;
    max-width: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
}

.logo{
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    height: 57px;
    width: auto;
    background:red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hq8q8eqg/7/